# change selection of dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

i have two drop down list and want to change the value of dropdown2 by selection of dropdown1
e.g. Select Subject from dropdown1 Computer science . dropdown2 show's Algorithms , operating system , Data structures. and by changing the category selection from dropdown1 to mathematics it will show algebra , integration .etc I want to use jquery only and no server trips on selection. all processing on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by using associative array and some little jQuery, So try this... Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p73qZ/)
HTML Code:

```
<select id="subject" name="subject">
  <option id='computerScience' value="1" selected>Computer science</option>
  <option id='mathematics' value="2">Mathematics</option>
</select>
<select name="chapters" id="chapters">
  <option value="1" selected>Algorithms</option>
  <option value="2">operating system</option>
  <option value="3">Data structures</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var subjects = {
    'computerScience':['Algorithms','operating system', 'Data structures'], 
    'mathematics':['algebra' , 'integration']
};

$('#subject').change(function(){
  var selectedSubject = $('#subject :selected').attr('id');
  $("#chapters option").remove();
  chapters = subjects[selectedSubject];
  for (i=0;i<chapters.length;i++)
  $('<option/>').val(chapters[i]).html(chapters[i]).appendTo('#chapters');
});
```

**Please be noted that the id of the subject dropdown options must match with the subjects array's key values in order to select the correct subjects.**

Answer (score 0):

i think that this plugin will do the trick [jCombo](http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/?lang=en)
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html (Maybe the best, start here)

http://r-ednalan.blogspot.com/2011/03/dynamic-select-box-using-jquery-ajax.html

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/using-jquery-ajax-populate-selection-list/

http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/

They explained with examples.

Comment: i want to do this on client side so no DB should be  involved